# Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, asp.net

In my Asp.Net 4.0 C# application I wanted to use chart control. Is there any chart control designed to work with asp.net 4.0 where my application is going to be deployed with the Azure Frame work. Suggest me with any informative links to move forward

Comment: .0 where my application is going to be deployed with the Azure Frame work. Suggest me with any informative links to move forward

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like your question already contained the answer :)

.NET 4 come with a large set of their own charting controls. Scott Guthrie has a post about it and also provides multiple links with examples how to use them from 4 Guys from Rolla

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/07/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx

**UPD:** Just to confirm that the charting control is in fact present in VS2010 - here's a screenshot of the control in the Toolbox:

[image]

Comment: Hi Artiom,
I didnt see any chart control for the asp.net in the toolbox. Please make it more clear for me

Comment: You are using VS2010, right? If you're still using VS2008 then you have to download the charting control, but you can't use .NET 4 in it anyway.. 

If you're using 2010 then just head over to the Data tab if you're in design view in a ASP.NET page, or just add an asp:Chart control to your page! I Have just tested it and it's there!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got it now. Previously my application is pointing to .Net 3.5 FW version.

Comment: .0 where my application is going to be deployed with the Azure Frame work. Suggest me with any informative links to move forward

Comment: You should ask a new question for this not extend the current one

Comment: What @Mark said :P
This is a completely different and unrelated question you're asking...