# What is the Windows event for showing the desktop?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, event-handling, windows-10

I want to have some code run when the user tells Windows to show the desktop, such as when the user presses Win+D. I am having issues finding what that event is. I tried using spy++, but couldn't find what I was looking for, and the documentation for things like this seem poor or nonexistent.

Specifically what I want to do is avoid hiding the window because I'm making a desktop overlay program, and having this as the desktop is precisely the purpose of the program. If there is an alternative to handling the Windows event to accomplish this, I would be fine with that. I saw [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32589338/2551829) answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work on Windows 10, which I need to support, along with 7 and 8.

Comment: Is this a winforms app that you are building?

Comment: I shouldn't imagine Windows feels any need to notify programs that this has happened.  What event(s) does your program receive?

Comment: Currently it only listens for set focus and position changed

Comment: I didn't ask what it was listening for.  What events does Windows send it?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. If I knew that I should be able to make it do what I need.