# Programmatically show the desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop, sendkeys

I am programming a Windows Form Application and I need to programmatically get back to the Desktop.

I tried this code, but it is not working:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

private void ToggleDesktop() {

SendKeys.Send("^({ESC}D)"); //<-- Semantic error, Should simulate: WIN+D

}
```

Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009623/c-keeping-window-visible-through-show-desktop-wind

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robgruen/2004/02/24/programmatically-showing-the-desktop-toggledesktop/

Comment: I tried both but isn't working

Comment: @FreaX The second link you were given is quite helpful. Look at my answer to see how to use it properly within your project.

Comment: Yeah, now I know. The code wasn't visible at the first time!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `Shell32.dll` windows assembly to do that.

Just add a reference to `C:\Windows\System32\Shell32.dll`, then go to the reference properties and put a `False` near `Embed Interop Types` (since the class you're going to use is `ShellClass`, which is interop.

Now, it's as simple as

```
Shell32.ShellClass objShel = new Shell32.ShellClass();
objShel.ToggleDesktop();
```

Comment: Note, you need to be running on an STA thread or you will get a weird exception.

Comment: i cant find documentation for Shell32.ShellClass

Comment: @Yotam how to use DllImport with Shell32.ShellClass in powershell?

Answer (score 3):

Also possible (tested under Windows 8.1):

Add COM reference to "Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation"
<sub>(c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll)</sub>

Then:

```
using Shell32;

Shell shellObject = new Shell();
shellObject.ToggleDesktop(); // WinXp: ((Shell32.IShellDispatch4)shellObject).ToggleDesktop();
```

Comment: Works on Win10 1909.