# wpf how to view desktop or go desktop by using user32

Tags: c#, wpf

hi i want to create application when i click the button it go to desktop, i mean when you press Win + D it go to desktop directly, i want to use user32 to be more practical, I want to use this method in the future too, but how?

i dont want to use this way, this road is a little weak :

```
II.Keyboard.KeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN);
II.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_D);
II.Keyboard.KeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN);
```

thank you for answer

Comment: no, but thanks Lei Yang for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598951/programmatically-show-the-desktop